# Unity 5 - Occlusion culling 2D error

Tags: c#, unity, culling, occlusion

I'm trying to set a Occlusion culling on my topdown 2D game. I have made a sprite object with a Occlusion Area on it.Once I try to bake it, it gives me the following error:

No Renderers that are marked static were found in the scene. Please mark all renderers that will never move as static in the inspector.
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

What exactly does this mean?

I'm using V5.3.2

Comment: It sounds like OP was actually looking for Frustum Culling (how do I avoid drawing objects that are outside the camera view frame), not Occlusion Culling (how do I avoid drawing objects that are behind an opaque barrier).

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the objects static which will be the part occlusion culling. The sprites/objects that will not move in runtime will have to be marked as static before baking. Make the objects static then system will get some renderer to work on. Then bake.

[image]

Occlusion culling is valid on only 3D mesh's. 2D sprites are not supported type. It's used on 3D objects. Usually 2D scenes doesn't require occlusion culling. **Or you have to have at least one static 3D object in the scene**

Comment: I believe this is not the case, as there is a [tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) on how to make it for both 2D and 3D

Comment: just recreated your problem. sprite is not supported type. use static 3D object to use in 2D. it will work on static 2D object but will not generate only for 2D objects. the tutorial is for 3D scene.

Comment: Okay, so I need to make 3D objects with the sprites as textures?

Comment: Just put a static 3D box in the side. Just a hack!!  If your game is 2D you are looking for wrong tools. Simple instantiation and destroy or enable disable will just work fine in 2D.

Comment: Then how do I detect if a object is out of the camera, to disable it?

Comment: Several ways. You can simply use collider and detect if triggers. Or you can https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html check visibility in camera. What kind of game are you creating? What's the problem specifically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41834/discussion-between-sp-and-vellosfree).